# Celery task creates a new model object, but django signals doesn't pick it up

Tags: python, django-models, celery

I've read around and see this has to do with concurrency, that celery can't edit the app variables because it's in a different thread from a python app. So instead I'm modifying the database by creating an object in the hope that django signal would've picked it up, but it's not. I'm doing this since I need to know if an update has occured in the back end so the SPA front end can fetch it automatically. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Django signals only work in-process.  So making a model change in celery will trigger the signal to occur in celery.  If you need to notify a single page app either (1) use a websocket or (2) pass the SPA the task_id so it can poll for when the task is complete and then take the necessary action.

Comment: Your insight is valid, yet something is still missing. How to communicate from the Celery worker back with the new id to the place where the WebSocket is maintained (the main Django app). Maybe the channels is the answer but then how to configure it, and make the workers also access it?

Comment: You could always POST back to the Django REST API from a Celery task when it comletes.